# Using ALT+Click to select text in columns with Notepad++ (Linux)

Tags: linux, notepad++, wine

I run Notepad++ both in Windows, and in Linux under Wine.  In Windows, I can hold Alt and click/drag to select characters in a column rather than line-by-line.

In Linux, holding Alt and clicking doesn't select anything.  Rather, it makes the cursor a hand tool which drags the window around.

Is there a setting to toggle on the alt-click column highlighting?  I've poked around in the settings and keyboard shortcuts, but didn't find anything that looked relevant.

Thank you.

Comment: Depending what distribution of linux and desktop environment you're using this might be a global shortcut in your linux GUI rather than an issue with Notepad++. I know in at least GNOME in the past that was a shortcut (Alt+Click to drag windows around). I never use that shortcut so I'm not sure if that's still a thing. Try and see if that shortcut drags around other windows on the desktop, if it does then you have your answer.

Comment: Thanks!  That was indeed the problem.

Answer (score 2):

In case anyone else runs into this:

[For Cinnamon desktop](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=123234): go to Preferences > System Settings > Windows.  Click on the Behavior tab.  Change the "Special key to move and resize windows" from Alt to Disabled (or a different key).

Voila, alt-select works again in Notepad++!

(The Mint Forums answer linked above is for an older version but I have confirmed that this works on Mint 20.1 with Cinnamon 4.8.6.)

Comment: I have the same problem when want to use "alt+click" in vscode.
In Linux Mint 20.2 Cinnamon: System Settings > (Preferences) Windows > Behavior: change "Special key to move and resize windows" from Alt to Disabled